# rake generate error with Octopress

Tags: rake

My Octopress blog is deployed, but I can't figure out the YAML issue when running 'rake generate'. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

---

dubipod$ **rake generate**

'## Generating Site with Jekyll'

remove .sass-cache/

remove source/stylesheets/screen.css

create source/stylesheets/screen.css

/Users/dubipod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse': couldn't parse YAML at line 67 column 14 (Psych::SyntaxError)

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:148:in `parse_stream'

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:119:in `parse'

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:106:in `load'

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:205:in `load_file'

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/lib/jekyll.rb:119:in `configuration'

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/jekyll-0.11.0/bin/jekyll:207:in `'

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'

from /Users/dubipod/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/jekyll:23:in `'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error and to fix it I removed the @ sign from my twitter username and the syntax error went away. The output says exactly where your error is: "couldn't parse YAML at line 67 column 14 (Psych::SyntaxError)"

**Syntax Error**

```
66 # Twitter
67 twitter_user: @joshschmelzle
```

**Fixed**

```
66 # Twitter
67 twitter_user: joshschmelzle
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just edit

```
  twitter_user:twitterName
```

**to**

```
  twitter_user: twitterName
```